# How can I generate a password for a shopify app

Tags: python, django, shopify

Following the [documentation](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api#getting-started), this is what I do to test in the console:

```
import os
import shopify

SHOPIFY_API_KEY = os.environ.get('SHOPIFY_API_KEY')
SHOPIFY_API_SECRET = os.environ.get('SHOPIFY_API_SECRET')
SHOPIFY_API_PASSWORD = '' # os.environ.get('SHOPIFY_API_PASSWORD')  # TODO: I don't have this

shop_url = "https://%s:%s@appappapp.myshopify.com/admin" % (SHOPIFY_API_KEY, SHOPIFY_API_PASSWORD)
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_site(shop_url)
shopify.Session.setup(api_key=SHOPIFY_API_KEY, secret=SHOPIFY_API_SECRET)
products = shopify.Product.find(limit=3)
```

And I of course get an:

```
pyactiveresource.connection.UnauthorizedAccess: Response(code=401, body="{"errors":"[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"}
```

I have no idea how to generate a password. My shopify connection is working as integrated with django, via SHOPIFY_API_KEY / SHOPIFY_API_SECRET, storing an access token in the session.

In the URL `https://app.shopify.com/services/partners/api_clients/<app-id>` I can generate secrets and refresh tokens, but no passwords.

How do I get this to work on the console? How can I generate a password for a shopify app?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to generate a Shopify password. Your API Key and Secret are all you need to get your app installed for a Partner app.

You need an API Key and password for private apps.
You need an API Key and Secret for Partner apps.

Essentially, you need to follow these steps.

```
1) setup your Shopify app using your API key and secret.

2) setup the permission url by specifying your store and scope

3) grab the values returned by the permission url in order to get your
Shopify permanent token. (you get the token by doing a call using
the params you got from step 2)

4) use the token you have to make all your API calls
```

Comment: Does this apply when I want to test from the console (no webapp)? The shop_url is `"https://%s:%s@appappapp.myshopify.com/admin" % (SHOPIFY_API_KEY, SHOPIFY_API_PASSWORD)`, so it needs a password. Could you please show some curl commands on how to achieve connection to shopify with the method that you have described?

Comment: You only need the password for private apps. This is given to you when you create the private app in your store. When you are using a partner app you don't need a password. the API Key and Secret are sufficient.